# Inequality of continuous functions

Tags: calculus

Let $u, v$ be continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and let $c>0$. Suppose that for all $x \in [a,b]$  we have the following inequality:

$$|u(x)-v(x)| \leq c \int_a^x |u(t)-v(t)| dt$$

Show that $u(x)=v(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$

My first thought was to consider $h(x)=|u(x)-v(x)|$ and try to show that $h=0$, but I got stuck. Also, I proved the inequality considering the case $c(b-a) \leq 1$, but I'm not sure how to continue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $H(x)=\int_a^xh(t)\,dt$. Then $H'=h$, $H'\le c\,H$ and $H(a)=0$.
$$
(e^{-ct}H)'=e^{-ct}(H'-c\,H)\le0.
$$
$e^{-ct}H$ is positive, decreasing and $H(a)=0$.

Comment: Ah! didn't notice this before I posted, just did the same thing in a different notation thats all. (+1)

Comment: No sir, I am not following

Answer (score 5):

An integral-equation flavored approach:

Set

$g(x) = \vert u(x) - v(x) \vert; \tag{1}$

then the given inequality may be written

$g(x) \le c\int_a^x g(t) dt = \int_a^x cg(t) dt; \tag{2}$

now apply [the integral form of Gronwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality), which, as far as the present purposes are concerned, may be taken to state that continuous $w(x)$ satisfying

$w(x) \le b + \int_a^x cw(t) dt, \tag{3}$

$b$ constant, also satisfy

$w(x) \le be^{\int_a^x cdt} = be^{c(x - a)}; \tag{4}$

note $g(x) \ge 0$ and (4) shows, since $b = 0$,

$g(x) \le 0.  \tag{5}$

We conclude that

$g(x) = 0, \tag{6}$

i.e.,

$u(x)  = v(x) \tag{7}$

for $x \in [a, b]$.

Comment: You have to love Gronwall! +1

Comment: Yuppers, gotta love ol' Gronwall!  Thanks!

Comment: This is the third or forth time I've seen its application on the MSE within the past two days.  Is it "that time of the semester?"

Comment: @Dr.MV:  Well, the summer ODE sessions are having midterms here at Cal . . .

Comment: that's lovely use of Grunwall!! (+1)

Comment: @r9m:  well, ol' Gronwall can look pretty cute against certain backdrops, no?

Answer (score 4):

Fix an $x_1 \in [a,b]$, then the function $h(x) = u(x) - v(x)$, satisfies,

$$|h(x)| \le c\int_a^x |h(x)|\,dx$$

Consider, $\displaystyle \sup\limits_{x \in [a,x_1]} |h(x)| = M_{x_1}$

Then, $$M_{x_1} = \sup\limits_{x \in [a,x_1]} |h(x)| \le c\sup\limits_{x \in [a,x_1]} \int_a^x |h(x)|\,dx \le M_{x_1}c(x_1-a)$$

Hence, if we choose an $x_1$ such that, $x_1-a < 1/c$ it must imply $M_{x_1} = 0$, thus $h(x) = 0$ in the interval $[a,x_1]$. This gives us the same scenario as in $[x_1,b]$ and we may conclude that $h(x) = 0$ on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Just one question! What assures me I can take x1 that close to a??

Comment: @JuanManuelCastro $x\in [a,b]$.

Comment: What I meant, is how may I extend this result in the whole interval!?

Comment: @JuanManuelCastro $a,c$ are fixed, that gives us an interval $[a,x_1]$ (with $x_1 = a+\frac{1}{2c} < a+\frac{1}{c}$) of positive $\frac{1}{2c}$ length where, $h(x)$ vanishes. Next we take the interval $[x_1,b]$ and choose $x_2$ in it similarly (so that $x_2 - x_1 = \frac{1}{2c}$) and eventually cover $[a,b]$ with subintervals of length $1/{2c}$ where $h(x)$ vanishes.