# $|g(x)| \leq K \int_a^x|g| \ \ \forall x \in I$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Let $I:=[a,b]$ and let $g: I \to \Bbb R$ be continuous on $I$. Suppose that there exists $K > 0$ such that $$|g(x)| \leq K \int_a^x|g| \ \ \forall x \in I.$$  Then $g(x) = 0\ \ \forall x \in I $.

I am stuck with the problem please help!

Comment: Deleted my earlier comment.  This follows right from Gronwells,  since you can set any $C$ in Gronwells, you have your function is bounded by $ce^{x-a}$ for all $c>0$,  taking limits, you get that it must be 0

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1355937/8271).

Answer (score 1):

We directly apply [Gronwall's inequality in its integral form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) to

$\vert g(x) \vert \leq K \int_a^x \vert g \vert dx = \int_a^x K\vert g \vert dx; \tag{1}$

as far as the present purposes are concerned, Gronwall's may be taken to state that continuous $w(x)$ on $I = [a, b]$ satisfying

$w(x) \le \beta + \int_a^x cw(t) dt, \tag{2}$

$\beta$ constant, also satisfy

$w(x) \le \beta e^{\int_a^x cdt} = \beta e^{c(x - a)}; \tag{3}$

since in the present case $\beta = 0$, we thus find that

$0 \le \vert g(x) \le 0 e^{\int_a^x Kdt} = 0; \tag{4}$

thus

$\vert g(x) \vert = 0, \tag{5}$

so

$g(x) = 0, x \in I. \tag{6}$

***QED!***